# load a page + ajax call automactically using external link (with Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that loads segments of info when links in the sidebar are clicked.

http://www.youarehere.im/other-financial-services.html

All works fine.

I also want to link to this page from the index.html file, but have the relevent section load in automatically, rather than its default state.

So on the home page, the "accounts" link loads up "other-financial-services.html" AND automatically requests the ajax call for the "accounts" link from the server.

Any ideas? I know this Jquery snippet is completly wrong but I am very new to front side scripting and am shooting in the dark!

HTML:

```
<div class="box accounting"><h2><a id="service_accounts">Accounting</a></h2></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
    var load_services = "other-financial-services.html";
    var accounts = "accounts.php";

    $('#service_accounts').click(function() {
        $.get(load_services).load(accounts);
    });
});
```

Comment: The sidebar in your example page URL doesn't work for me in FF8.

Comment: FYI: Your meta content tag isn't closed and you have an error in ajax.js (line 46, `.get(load_services).load(accounts);`) that is causing the menu not to work in FF8 and IE9

Comment: Rory, thanks for the heads-up on the meta tag. I knew the Ajax.js was pbroken when I posted, now fixed.

Comment: actually I meant thanks syserr0r for meta tag heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like:

```
<div class="box accounting"><h2><a id="service_accounts">Accounting</a></h2></div>
<div id='target'></div>

$('#service_accounts').click(function(){
    //load the html page int the div with id=target (of course is just an example)
    $('#target').load(load_services);
    $.get(accounts, function(data){
        //do something with data returned from the server
     });
});
```

Comment: Aside from a few JS errors he has the AJAX sub-menu working, from what I understand he wants to link directly to a __sub-menu__ from another page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want these variables to be changed depending on where you opened the page from?

```
var load_services = "other-financial-services.html";
var accounts = "accounts.php";
```

That would mean you need to find a way to pass a parameter to this page, so you can switch between values.
Unfortuantely, I lack any decent PHP knowledge, but I reckon it should be possible to add

```
?ajaxloadselector=1
```

to your URL?

Then you can just edit the URLS in the pages that link to this one, and on this page, you make a switch that fills in the variables depending on the 'ajaxloadselector' parameter that is passed.

Comment: From what I understand, he wants to be able to link to a __sub-menu__ page directly, that is the problem.

Comment: Which is loaded in via Ajax on the page itself, isn't it? If I misinterpreted, apologies :-)

Comment: I may have misunderstood your answer, my apologies :$

Answer (score 0):

On the home page, if you want to link to the '*Accounting*' sub-menu option of the '*Financial Services*' page, make a link like:

`http://www.youarehere.im/other-financial-services.html#accounts`

and js code similar to

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) { // the URL contains an anchor
  // click the navigation item corresponding to the anchor
  var anchor = '#' + url.split('#')[1];
  $('#load_' + anchor).click();
}
```

So that whenever you load a page with a `#<something>` in the url, the element `#load_<something>` is clicked on

*Code shamelessly stolen from http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2007/12/04/anchor-based-url-navigation-with-jquery (and modified)*

Comment: I really like the idea of this solution, unfortunately I cannot get the JS to work as yet. Followed suggestion and inserted your code after document.ready() `code`$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) { // the URL contains an anchor
  // click the navigation item corresponding to the anchor
    var anchor = '#' + url.split('#')[0];
  $('#load_' + anchor).click();
}

Comment: I have seen the changes you have made to your code, you would need to place the above code at the bottom of the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` as the above code tries to 'click' the link which does nothing at the moment as the click event is not setup yet (it is further down the file).

Comment: In your code you have `url.split('#')[0]`, it should be `url.split('#')[1]` as you want the text __after__ the `#` (`accounts` in my example, so it would 'click' on `#load_accounts`)

Comment: You can find a slightly smaller copy of `ajax.js` __[here](http://pastebin.com/eBvkCkLN)__. Although I haven't been able to test it, it should work given that all the sidebars have an `id` that starts with `load_` and the text after the `load_` matches the page name.

Comment: Made some more corrections to the _smaller_ `ajax.js`, one of my corrections was undone in the latest version, oops! Get it __[here](http://pastebin.com/4C7EEYJH)__. Serves me right for trying to rush it...comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)